# Different returns for equal requests

Tags: uber-api

When I try to request a trip for certain users the API returns me that the `product_id` is invalid.

For other users in the same `location` and `product_id` returns the fare data.

I'm looking for the `product_id` in `/products` endpoint.

Sample request:

```
URL: https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/estimate (POST)
{
    "start_latitude": -30.030571,
    "start_longitude":  -51.194116,
    "end_latitude": -30.034647,
    "end_longitude": -51.217658,
    "product_id": "PRODUCT_ID"
}
```

Can help me understand what might happen?

Comment: Without a specific example it can be hard to pinpoint the exact reason, but just theorizing here perhaps the other user is not allowed to take trips through that app in the API. 

Or perhaps a product ID is available for one user you are checking and not the other, e.g. UberX VIP https://help.uber.com/h/169bef66-3f08-4a97-8a2c-a6098e6eaba4.  Just spitballing possible answers.

Comment: What's strange is that I use the product_id itself returning in the [GET] /products endpoint. I checked and it usually happens with UberX.